# How to extract certain database from full Mysql dump?

Tags: linux, backup, shell, mysql

I have regular backups of my mysql server.For convenience I set it up as a single Mysql nightly dump. Now I need to restore one of the databases from the dump.

How do I restore a single database from the whole Mysql dump? It is a pretty big file as well. It is about 800mb.

I am on Debian Wheezy 32bit

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the --one-database option from mysql command.

```
mysql -u root -p --one-database your_db < full_backup.sql
```

You first need to create a **blank database** same name as present in the full_backup.sql which you want to restore.

For more info on --one-database refer to the documentation. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_one-database

Comment: note that there are issues with `--one-database` options, see http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=40477

Comment: one might want to use tool https://github.com/kedarvj/mysqldumpsplitter to extract only one database (or only one table) etc from dump, and import that